# how to call an activity by clicking the menu in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having main activity called OverallActivity. here I wrote a code to add menu, by selecting the menu I want to perform an action in another activity.
Eg: main Activity: OverallActiviry
         menus: Action1 and Action2
If i click action1 it have to call the subActivity1 one. and If i press Action2,it have call the another activity(subActivity2), in that subActivity2 I want set the Listview to display the array(string() value returned by subActivity1. If anyone knows please revert me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I misunderstood your question, so now here's some correction:

To launch an activity, use Shashank Kadne's code in the code from TofeeqAhmad.

To pass data to `subActivity2` you can add additional data to the intent that opens the Activity, in your case, an array of `CharSequence` items:

```
CharSequence[] sequences = ...;
intent.putExtra("resultsFromActivity1", sequences);
```

Then, in your activity's `onCreate` handler you could check whether the intent contains an extra named "operation" an what its value is:

```
CharSequence[] items = itent.getCharSequenceExtra("resultsFromActivity1");
if (items != null)
{
    // Display the items
}
```

Comment: Thank you This Just same as my expectation.

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aspiresys.socialapp/com.aspiresys.socialapp.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException"  It shows the error like this. Am I want to do any changes in manifest file

Comment: I can not tell without the full stack trace and error message. I don't know which element is `null`.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. Mistakenly i i had declared the Listview before the onCreat(). Thats what a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Override this method----

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.new_game:
   // start activty here
    return true;
case R.id.help:
  // start activty here
    return true;
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aspiresys.socialapp/com.aspiresys.socialapp.ActivityTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException"  It shows the error like this. Am I want to do any changes in manifest file

Comment: check these link for this problem;;;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443091/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Check part about responding to user action.

Answer (score 1):

use Intents. Pass the class of the Activity to be called.

Add below lines in the listener to call subActivity1

```
Intent i = new Intent(OverallActiviry.this,subActivity1.class)
startActivity(i);
```