# android class not found execption

Tags: android, google-maps

i am making an googlemap application in which i am showing map in device ,its working fine,but now i want to show the distance between two cities ,its giving me class not found exception.i am using fragment activity for application ,and i want to draw path between two cities.,but i am getting exception

```
     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements RoutingListener{
    private GoogleMap _googleMap=null;
      protected LatLng start;
        protected LatLng end;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            try
            {
                //loading map
                initilizeMap();
                _googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                _googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);       

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   private void initilizeMap() {
            if(_googleMap==null)
            {
                _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap(); 
            CameraUpdate center=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(18.013610,-77.498803));
                CameraUpdate zoom=  CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
                  _googleMap.moveCamera(center);
                _googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

                start = new LatLng(18.015365, -77.499382);
                end = new LatLng(18.012590, -77.500659);

                Routing routing = new Routing(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING);
                routing.registerListener(this);
                routing.execute(start, end);
             if (_googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry!  map cannot be created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        }

       @Override
        public void onRoutingFailure() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    @Override
        public void onRoutingStart() {
        }
      @Override
        public void onRoutingSuccess(PolylineOptions mPolyOptions) {
              PolylineOptions polyoptions = new PolylineOptions();
              polyoptions.color(Color.BLUE);
              polyoptions.width(10);
              polyoptions.addAll(mPolyOptions.getPoints());
              _googleMap.addPolyline(polyoptions);

              // Start marker
              MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
              options.position(start);
              options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
              _googleMap.addMarker(options);

              // End marker
              options = new MarkerOptions();
              options.position(end);
              options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green));  
              _googleMap.addMarker(options);
            }
    }




  here is maniefestfile

   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAw2l6gw-SmJZZ9LlsFA49OR3L7CT7vFSM" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have the Main Class? Have you declared it in the Manifest?

Comment: @NunChai yes sir.,i have declared this in my mainefest

Comment: Can you post the relevant manifest snippet? Plus also check all your imports.

Comment: @NunChai ok sir..,i post my mainifest with editing my code

Comment: @rajshree can you post your manifest snippet, Are you sure that you specify the class with whole package name, Also post your xml

Comment: This will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102232/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-classnPlease check that the Android Private libraries is checked or not.

Comment: @rajshree i thing problem in activity deceleration manifest.

Comment: @Yugesh sir.,i am posting my maniefest file

Comment: @rajshree you posted the manifest file coding.

Comment: @Yugesh sir i am posting

Comment: @rajshree have you tried what i said

Comment: @Kalai.G yes sir..,i have added my library..,i have done that

Comment: @rajshree am not able to see your manifest file details here.how you can add the library files.

Comment: @Yugesh sir my code is not posting...,when i am editing it

Comment: @rajshree did you get the solution.no means say how you add the library file into your project.

Comment: @Yugesh sir i am posting my maniefest only..,because its not posting all data

Comment: @Yugesh sir i have edited my code...,in that i have maniefest also

Comment: @Arju sir..,i have edited my code.in which i have shown my manifestfile

Comment: @rajshree k.say how you add the library into your project.

Comment: @Yugesh sir..,firstli i installed googleplay library from sdkmanager,then import it in my project..

Comment: what's  `  <permission
        android:name="com.example.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
` these two permissions

Comment: @rajshree Arju is right.delete this `info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE` from manifest

Comment: @Yugesh sir yes sir.,i have deleted..and its working..,thanku

Comment: @Arju sir thanku its working...,but i have one more dought...,is there any way to show limited citie sin spinner in googlemap

Comment: Yes there are options to limit that, You should check the Google Api

Comment: Iam also a learner , no need to call us sir. You are welcome :)