# Android import android.app.FragmentActivity cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I made the following steps on my project and on the appcompat_v7 library:
right click > Android Tools > Add Support Library..

After that everything gone crazy.. I can't import the android.app.FragmentActivity library.
Here is my java build path:
[image]

And the Android tab:
[image]

Adding the android-support-v4.jar didn't help. Please help me!

Comment: have u got any error ?

Comment: It should be `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: It was working before I did the steps I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by changing `android.app.FragmentActivity` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and after that I did the steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102232/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-classn).

Comment: In case of getting this error after following this step: "The import android.support cannot be resolved"
[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299898/the-import-android-support-cannot-be-resolved) is a good solution

Answer (score 2):

There is no `android.app.FragmentActivity`. It is `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

Comment: It was working before I did the steps I mentioned.
If I use the android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity i got ClassNotFoundException

Comment: @Crash-ID: "It was working before I did the steps I mentioned" -- since there is no class named `android.app.FragmentActivity` in the Android SDK or support libraries, I do not see how it could have worked.

Comment: @Crash-ID: Since you have provided no code and no stack trace, I cannot help you further.