# While i am extending ActionBarActivity, gives error. Why?

Tags: android

i am using Action Bar in my App, extends ActionBarActivity , but it is giving following error in Logcat,

```
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): Process: com.example.a_bar, PID: 7062
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a_bar/com.example.a_bar.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.a_bar.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.a_bar-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.a_bar-1, /system/lib, /data/downloads]]
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 21:59:53.252: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.a_bar.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.a_bar-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.a_bar-1, /system/lib, /data/downloads]]
```

Manifest is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a_bar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a_bar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

style.xml is as below,

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity is as below,

```
package com.example.a_bar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

i have added as library project android-support-v7-appcompat, in my App.
And added theme into Manifest,

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

My App get crashed while stated . 
Why ClassNotFoundException generated ? But when i extend Activity instead of ActionBarActivity it is Running .

Comment: Post your code and AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I see your updated code, do you have the correct package name on your class? I am not seeing one at all. Is your IDE not showing your warnings?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path

Comment: @Jared Burrows, yes i have used the correct package name

Comment: Your `AndroidManifest.xml`, `MainActivity.java` and `style.xml` are correct. Do you have anything in your `activity_main.xml` layout? Did you just create/import this project?

Comment: i just created new project in my IDE. activity_main.xml is nothing but the by default FrameLayout. When i extends Activity instead of ActionBarActivity, then it is running.

Comment: You should be using Android Studio. Since you are just starting, you should switch now. Have you tried cleaning your project, usually this is an issue in Eclipse?

Comment: @ Jared Borrows , i tried all , previously.

Comment: @ Jared Borrows, Thanks , Now it is working for ActionBarActivity also, i just update the sdk Android Support Libraries, and restart the Eclipse. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` because `minSdkVersion` of your project is 11, so the ActionBar will already be included in your app even if you don't extend `ActionBarActivity`. You need to import **support library** for `ActionBar` only when your application's `minSdkVersion` is **less than 11**.

Just import `android.app.Activity` and extend your class to `Activity` only.

Comment: He most likely wants to use `AppCompat` for `Material Design`. Swapping his imports avoids his question.

Answer (score 0):

There are dependency issue. add support-v4 library and hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is not located in `Support V4`.