# Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application and added fire-base crashlytics,but in some devices i am getting below issue continuously

Can some one help me please how can i resolve this issue

### gradle:

```
   dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    //google services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
```

### Error:

```
  Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.karvyclick.fos-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app/com.karvyclick.fos-1/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Comment: Using proguard ?

Comment: buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules_new.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules_new.pro'

        }
    }

Comment: @Redman please check ,my above comment

Comment: proguard is off . Are you using multidex ?

Comment: yes i am using multidex

Comment: i updated gradle please check once

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399572/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist-after

Comment: @AbhiRam any solution ?

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, you must add to gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
```

You can see comments from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/1OFaL07H5HU)

Answer (score 1):

> Try changing Proguard.cfg file to exclude obfuscating android.gms.*

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the play-services-ads to **18.1.1**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

As Described in [release note](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes)

- Added dependencies on **play-services-measurement** and **play-services-measurement-sdk**.

**Apps no longer need to add** these dependencies explicitly.