# Android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path

Tags: java, android

Here's the exception message that I get when I launch the app.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: net.johnhany.opencv3jniPID: 10721
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{net.johnhany.opencv3jni/net.johnhany.opencv3jni.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "net.johnhany.opencv3jni.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/net.johnhany.opencv3jni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.johnhany.opencv3jni-1lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivityActivityThread.java:2322)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivityActivityThread.java:2474)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.ess$800(ActivityThread.java:144) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessageActivityThread.java:1359) at
>   android.os.Handler.sage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loopLooper.java:155) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.mainActivityThread.java:5696) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeMethod.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.runZygoteInit.java:1028)
>   at com.android.internal.os.Init.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "net.johnhany.opencv3jni.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/net.johnhany.opencv3jni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.johnhany.opencv3jni-1/lib/arm/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClassBaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassClassLoader.java:511) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassClassLoader.java:469) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivityInstrumentation.java:1083) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivityActivityThread.java:2312)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivityActivityThread.java:2474) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.ess$800(ActivityThread.java:144)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessageActivityThread.java:1359) 
>   at android.os.Handler.sage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loopLooper.java:155)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.mainActivityThread.java:5696)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeMethod.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.runZygoteInit.java:1028) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.Init.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)  Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.johnhany.opencv3jni.ty at
>   java.lang.Class.classForNameNative Method) at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.Class(ClassLoader.java:781) at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.Class(ClassLoader.java:841) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassClassLoader.java:504) ... 13 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available 05-18 16:01:27.927 645-1928/?
>   E/ActivityManager: App crashedProcess: net.johnhany.opencv3jni

Comment: Please always format Stracktraces to make it more readable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also add some more details what you're doing and what do you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 18):

My problem solved using use multi dex:

```
android {
defaultConfig {

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}
dependencies 
{
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey i have some strange behavior, in some devices i have the DexPathList problem, my app class extends to `MultiDexApplication` but the problem persists with the class `com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnector` very weird, this was after an update of Firebase to 15.0.x then i use the `attachBaseContext` method in the same class and that fixed the problem (i thought that is unnecessary because i'm extending to Dex class), can you explain why? or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Great!!! It solved my problem. When I run my app on android 24 it's normal. But android 19 the app crashed. this solution solved my problem.

Comment: All are there by default, but still this issue is coming

Answer (score 6):

I was using Instant Run in Android Studio and same error happened to me because I was installing the `debug.apk` that was created inside `outputs\apk` folder and it turns to be smaller and with missing classes because it probably was the outcome of an instant run.

Some pointed on Turning Off instant run but instead of turning instant run off just build the apk by clicking on `Build->Build apk` in the menu and use that apk for testing.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this error happens, when the application fails to find the launcher activity.

Suggestions :

1. Check your mainfest file for the right launcher activity
2. Check your main activity is extending from activity or Appcompatactivity
3. Clean the project and build it again.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I removed **apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'** from module level gradle file by mistake.

After putting it again, it starts working again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this Diable preDexLibraries

In your `app` module .gradle file

```
android {
 dexOptions
            {
                preDexLibraries false
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution:
1.Change the application name in AndroidManifest to full path
2.Clean Project
3.Rebuild Project
4.Build APK

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AndroidX`, this is the MultiDex lib

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```

also

```
defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and make your application class inherent from `MultiDexApplication`

Answer (score -3):

I had this problem once and clearly remember:

**My Mistake**
I created two projects with same name in different folders.

**My Solution**
On discovering this i deleted the older project and then :
 1.Clean Project
 2.Rebuild
 3.Run