# Android E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f090030

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm having some problem making fragments show up in screen when i select them in the bottom bar.

Here is some context:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.pkg.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.helpjobapp.android.ExploreFragment;
import com.helpjobapp.android.HomeFragment;
import com.helpjobapp.android.MyAccountFragment;
import com.helpjobapp.android.MyServicesFragment;
import com.helpjobapp.android.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
        openFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance("", ""));
    }

    public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home_fragment:
                            openFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance("", ""));
                            return true;
                        case R.id.explore_fragment:
                            openFragment(ExploreFragment.newInstance("", ""));
                            return true;
                        case R.id.myservices_fragment:
                            openFragment(MyServicesFragment.newInstance("", ""));
                            return true;
                        case R.id.myaccount_fragment:
                            openFragment(MyAccountFragment.newInstance("", ""));
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.pkg.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

This code is making the app to stop. It already opens with the message that stopped.

Am i missing something?

if i comment this method in the OnCreate method, it stops crashing.

```
// openFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance("", ""));
```

EDIT: Logcat output

```
8003-8003/com.helpjobapp.android E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f090030 (com.helpjobapp.android:id/container) for fragment HomeFragment{cfd48e4 #0 id=0x7f090030}
2020-03-25 00:50:3

2020-03-25 00:25:09.325 5523-5523/com.helpjobapp.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.helpjobapp.android, PID: 5523
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.helpjobapp.android/com.helpjobapp.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.helpjobapp.android.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.helpjobapp.android-oVVLDVUTFxke6gTer7JWSg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.helpjobapp.android-oVVLDVUTFxke6gTer7JWSg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/nav_home"
            android:visible="true" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/nav_search"
            android:visible="true" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_myservices"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_myservices"
            android:title="@string/nav_myservices"
            android:visible="true" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:title="@string/nav_account"
            android:visible="true" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you add the error message from the logcat?

Comment: @sadat, edited question incluing the logcat output.

Comment: You're getting `MainActivity  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class  on path: DexPathList`, there are several reasons for this error, please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042107/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path).

Comment: @Zain i dont think thats the main problem... the E/FragmentManager points that no view was found. how so?

Comment: Please check again. You might have another exception.