# Lowering minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android

I made an application but I set minSdkVersion 28 and my app doesn't work on most of the devices
and now i'm trying to lower minSdkVersion to 26 but I run into this error and I really can't solve this.
I hope that you guys can help me out with this.
I also inform you that when I switch minSdkVersion back to 28 I have no error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: DIRECT, PID: 24778
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{DIRECT/DIRECT.a_home_activity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "DIRECT.a_home_activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "DIRECT.a_home_activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/DIRECT-fFtl3y4AoyQ_ZmSr7m-ynQ==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
            ... 6 more
```

[My application for Android 8+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greekuniversityapplication)

```
int main(void) {
   printf("Thank you for your help!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the app need to use api 28 and above?

Comment: @Ticherhaz I upoloaded my application on Google Play Store and I liked some of the api 28 and above features and i wanted to keep them.. I separated the functions and I can't understand why I doesn't work.

Comment: have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042107/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took off some of the functions used at SKD 28+ and problem solved. Apparently, Android Studio and its compiler cannot understand that I separate the functions depending on the sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT and it crashes even if shouldn't. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **File -> Invalide Cache and restart**

Comment: Already tried it.. Unfortunately nothing works. I even created a new project and copied everything from the original one.