# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in android 4.0 After Adding the Ad Mob in App

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

After Adding the Ad Mob in App , its working in  higher version above 5.0 but its not working in 4.0 , i am getting the following exception

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service g2eandroid.srs.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "g2eandroid.srs.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/g2eandroid.srs-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/g2eandroid.srs-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2570)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "g2eandroid.srs.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/g2eandroid.srs-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/g2eandroid.srs-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting exception else no one can help

Comment: Thanks A lot  Redman for provided valuable code. Its working Fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please create a class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

    public class EnableMultiDex extends MultiDexApplication {
        private static EnableMultiDex enableMultiDex;
        public static Context context;

        public EnableMultiDex(){
            enableMultiDex=this;
        }

        public static EnableMultiDex getEnableMultiDexApp() {
            return enableMultiDex;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            context = getApplicationContext();

        }
    }
```

and in your manifest give android:name="packagename.EnableMultiDex"

eg:

```
<application
    android:name="YourPakageName.EnableMultiDex"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/wowio_launch_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:node="replace">
```

Let me know whether it solved your issue.

Comment: Are you sure this fixes ClassNotFound? The documentation specifically says this addresses the dex method count, which is not mentioned

Comment: I faced exactly the same problem and this helped me to solve that.Let us know whether it solves his also.:)

Comment: Its Working fine for me.

Comment: @cricket_007 it really works in some cases i saw atleast 30+ people fixed this error with this answer ,   SachinVarma you should give credit to me when you copy pasted  answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479407/6478047

Comment: When he asked the question i was not able to remember the place from where i got this code,but i applied it in my project that's all i know.So i posted the answer,and after seeing your comment i searched and i was able to see that i was taken the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106420/android-studiojava-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-compo, there i have mentioned your answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path. Sorry at first i was not able to remember these much.But you are right