# NoClassDefFoundError Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleDispatcher

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to try out the new lifecycle stuff from google (https://developer.android.com/arch) but getting a crash on app open. All I have done is add the dependencies. Is anyone else having this problem?

LOG:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.duetandroid.app.mock, PID: 17857
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleDispatcher;
at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.onCreate(LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.java:35)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.duetandroid.app.mock-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.duetandroid.app.mock-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.duetandroid.app.mock-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.onCreate(LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.java:35) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751) 
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'
compile 'com.sylversky.fontreplacer:fontreplacer:1.0'
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
compile 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479463/2914140.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you use Proguard? If so, try to turn it off:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    useProguard false
}
```

Or you can add custom rule to your Proguard config:

```
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
```

Comment: I had `minifyEnabled true`, `useProguard false`. But yup thanks setting `minifyEnabled false` worked. Thanks.

Comment: I then had to add `multiDexEnabled true` as I assume it pushed me over the dex limit

Comment: Why would Proguard be enabled in **debug** mode?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it's pretty common to use minifyEnabled true + useProguard false for debug builds so Proguard may look disabled but minifyEnabled uses the same config to decide what parts of code base should be removed. In this case it obviously removed too much.

Comment: This is not working for me, I am unable pass my unit test classes because of this error.

Answer (score 5):

Add the dependencies in the build.gradle of the app in my scenario was using a library that needed those dependencies

For android X

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

Make sure android X is enabled with gradle.properties and Jetfier enabled

```
     android.useAndroidX=true
     android.enableJetifier=true
```

For support versions

```
   implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs even without Proguard.  Today I could create the problem by creating the sample Flutter app in Android Studio and then running 'flutter pub upgrade'.

The solution that worked for me was to add to the app build.gradle file under 'dependencies'

> dependencies {
>       ...
>       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
>   }

If your app uses androidx, add to the gradle.properties file:

> android.useAndroidX=true
>   android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 1):

I was using some gradle configurations

```
android.enableR8.desugaring=false
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

To work again I removed `android.enableR8.desugaring=false` of gradle.properties file