# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry; at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity

Tags: java, android

I am facing this issue even though, I am starting a new project.
I removed Proguard as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075089/noclassdeffounderror-landroid-arch-lifecycle-lifecycledispatcher), but no luck so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please share your logcat. Otherwise, we cannot help.

Comment: are you trying with debug?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry;
        at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:56)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:62)
        at com.abracket.aaaaaa.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:6)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)

Comment: yes, I am trying with debug

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I am facing the same problem. please add an answer to this question @D.Rathore