# Xamarin Ap crashes updating Xamarin.Forms to 4.3.0.991211

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have updated Xamarin.Forms from Version 4.3.0.94... to 4.3.0.991211.

After successfully building and deploying the app, the app crashes during start.

VisualStudio-Output:

> 11-24 10:30:59.364 D/AndroidRuntime(11780): Shutting down VM 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780): Process: de.mva.example, PID:
>   11780 11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):
>   **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry;** 11-24 10:30:59.366
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.(SupportActivity.java:47)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:34)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:67)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   md59eb2629331d1deb5b887ca2339838830.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:24)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 11-24 10:30:59.366
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at
>   android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1232)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 11-24 10:30:59.366
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-24 10:30:59.366
>   E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780): **Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry"** on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/de.mva.example-EZmaiqQQu4tjJwFZc2RHYA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.mva.example-EZmaiqQQu4tjJwFZc2RHYA==/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/de.mva.example-EZmaiqQQu4tjJwFZc2RHYA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib]] 11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>   11-24 10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 11-24
>   10:30:59.366 E/AndroidRuntime(11780):     ... 21 more Unhandled
>   Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

csproj:

> Debug
>       AnyCPU
>       {0393D583-541C-43B7-8693-ABD7B6548E6F}
>       {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
>       Library
>       Properties
>       myProject
>       myProject
>       512
>       true
>       Resources\Resource.Designer.cs
>       Off
>       v8.1
>       Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
>       armeabi%3barmeabi-v7a%3bx86
>       
>       
>       
>             
>       true
>       full
>       false
>       bin\Debug\
>       DEBUG;TRACE
>       prompt
>       4
>       None
>       false
>       false
>       false
>       true
>       false
>       true
>       Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler
>       btls
>       false      
>       pdbonly
>       true
>       bin\Release\
>       TRACE
>       prompt
>       4
>       false
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       false
>       false
>       false
>       true
>       false
>       false      
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.3.0.991211\lib\MonoAndroid81\FormsViewGroup.dll
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Refractored.FloatingActionButton.2.1.0\lib\MonoAndroid10\Refractored.Fab.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Syncfusion\Syncfusion.Linq.Android.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Syncfusion\Syncfusion.SfCalendar.Android.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Syncfusion\Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.Android.dll
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.1.1.1.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.28.0.0.3\lib\monoandroid81\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.3.0.991211\lib\MonoAndroid81\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
>       
>       
>         False
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.3.0.991211\lib\MonoAndroid81\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll
>       
>       
>         ..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.4.3.0.991211\lib\MonoAndroid81\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll
>             
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>       
>             
>       
>       
>       
>             </Target>
>      </Target>   -->            
>       
>         Dieses Projekt verweist auf mindestens ein NuGet-Paket, das auf diesem Computer fehlt. Verwenden Sie die
>   Wiederherstellung von NuGet-Paketen, um die fehlenden Dateien
>   herunterzuladen. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter
>   "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105". Die fehlende Datei
>   ist "{0}".

Android-Manifest:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="de.mva.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">    
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />     
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     
      <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:theme="@style/myProjectTheme">
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

I tried to use "ProGuard". But -keep... didn't change anything..
Two days "googling": no solution found :(

I'm happy for any solution / suggestion

Comment: Android Manifest is missing, here it comes:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="de.mva.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:theme="@style/myProjectTheme"></application>
</manifest>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075089/noclassdeffounderror-landroid-arch-lifecycle-lifecycledispatcher

Comment: Could you provide the code sample for us to reproduce the error?

Comment: You can download the complete code here: vereinstool.net/downs/For_StackOverflow.7z

Comment: When i run the app, i get the cpmplier error in style.xml. i comment something and run it to get the error `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError:** 'Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistry;'`. i need some time to make a new app, i will feedback asap.

Comment: @WndyZang: Thank you for your support. In the meantime, I continue to use the old version of Xamarin.Forms (4.3.0.94...)