# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.tag.instagramdemo/com.tag.instagramdemo.example.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.tag.instagramdemo.example.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.tag.instagramdemo-RPnVNzMWpTMdxgTvSQKfiQ==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.tag.instagramdemo-RPnVNzMWpTMdxgTvSQKfiQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.tag.instagramdemo-RPnVNzMWpTMdxgTvSQKfiQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.tag.instagramdemo-RPnVNzMWpTMdxgTvSQKfiQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tag.instagramdemo-RPnVNzMWpTMdxgTvSQKfiQ==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

I get this error when I run my code and I have no idea what the issue is. Please help me... (Tell me if you need more info).

Comment: Can you provide the code of the Activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path)

Comment: Why do you need activity code?

Comment: Did you define MainActivity in manifest file?