# FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MainAcitivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android

I have searched extensively to find a solution for this issue and tried what I see has been suggested in the past.

Things I tried:
Deleted *.iml files locally
Deleted .idea files locally
Removed the project
Closed Android Studio and re-imported

Invalidated cached
Cleaned and re-builded. 
I'm assuming what caused the problem is moving MainActivity to a newly created package. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
2019-02-23 17:04:15.948 5842-5842/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp, PID: 5842
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp.ui.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp-UUO7m3VwjvpzPBPoUp-2AA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp-UUO7m3VwjvpzPBPoUp-2AA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp.ui.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp-UUO7m3VwjvpzPBPoUp-2AA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ssowens.android.myweatherapp-UUO7m3VwjvpzPBPoUp-2AA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523167/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path)

Comment: are you using multidex?