# ClassNotFoundException with Apache POI in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, apache-poi

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException for an app thats using Apache POI. I've tried running tests without Apache and it works fine, but when I add Apache's jars, it gives me this error: 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mathcountsassign.MainActivity"`

I've already tried cleaning the app, deleting the build file, reinstalling the jars, and re-importing the project. All the jar files are in libs.

My build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mathcountsassign"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/commons-collections4-4.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-compress-1.18.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-examples-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-excelant-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-scratchpad-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar')
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mathcountsassign">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.mathcountsassign.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Longer Logcat message:

```
    Process: com.example.mathcountsassign, PID: 25155
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathcountsassign/com.example.mathcountsassign.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.mathcountsassign.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mathcountsassign-OBA_3amy6pZqKsYm6MIhpw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mathcountsassign-OBA_3amy6pZqKsYm6MIhpw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at ...
```

Comment: did you tried this solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48011025/4614550