# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity?

Tags: android, exception, classnotfoundexception

For my Android application, I get the following error in Google Play's developer console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/PACKAGE_NAME-1/pkg.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/PACKAGE_NAME-1/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
```

Although this error appears extremely rarely (and can probably be neglected), I find it cleaner to have a error-free developer console :) And furthermore, I would just like to know the causes for this error.

*Yes, it seems as if there was a class that could not be found. But why? How can I prevent this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update(4/26/15):

After further research I believe you are right in the fact that its definitely a user error. The `[/mnt/asec/PACKAGE_NAME-1/pkg.apk]` most likely means they are trying to  move your app to the SD card. Please read here:

[Android intermittent class not found run time exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483947/android-intermittent-class-not-found-run-time-exception)

["Unable to instantiate activity" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025582/unable-to-instantiate-activity-error)

[Android: Unable to instantiate activity / ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820554/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-classnotfoundexception)

### Original:

This is a Java RuntimeException as seen by Logcat. I've seen this happen many times before when I have not added the Activity to manifest correctly.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/PACKAGE_NAME-1/pkg.apk]
```

Comment: Thank you! My manifest is okay, of course. This is why I wrote that the bug occurs extremely seldom. `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" ...><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity>` Can this be the user's device's fault as it probably doesn't load the manifest correctly or so?

Comment: I believe you are right in the fact this is a user error, please read my updated response :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) So they are probably using a third-party app to move my app to the SD card although they shouldn't?

Comment: I am guessing so. If the default(natural) way of moving the app to the sd card is not available, technically they should not do it, so it must be a 3rd party application.