# I keep getting this Error on my Launcher Themes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass

Tags: java, android

Below is the actual error from developer console.
My launcher theme's have an app so the user can apply themes, contact me, etc...

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red/bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red-1.apk]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1624)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red in         loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red-1.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1616)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is my android manifest for the app. Forgot to add it when i first posted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="4.4"     package="bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/theme_title" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".HelperActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.THEME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/theme_title" android:name=".Icons" />
    <activity android:label="@string/wp_theme_title" android:icon="@drawable/wallpaper_icon2" android:name=".Wallpaper" android:screenOrientation="nosensor" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/theme_title" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:name=".Docks">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/theme_title" android:icon="@drawable/theme_icon" android:name="bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red.GoLauncher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.gowidget" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red.DocksProvider" android:authorities="bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red.DocksProvider" />
    <receiver android:label="@string/analog_gadget" android:icon="@drawable/ic_widget_analog_clock" android:name="bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red.AnalogClockWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.oldName" android:value="com.android.deskclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/analog_appwidget" />
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe you have not declared an activity in manifest and trying to access it.

Comment: Please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11112082/1278748

Comment: I see your referring to the [/mnt/asec/PACKAGE_NAME-1/pkg.apk] BUT my error referrs to [/data/app/bigdx.golauncher.serenity.red-1.apk] which is local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the "HelperActivity" was being allowed to have the Component set to 0, and it will cause the app to error when the user tries to open the app from the market, or from the app drawer.   Also having the APEX intent, in the helper activity, was removing the Apex compatibility when the "HelperActivity" activity was no longer accessible.

This thread is now answered.

For a more suitable substitute, you would want to use the SET_COMPONENT_ENABLED flags with "KILL_APP" flags not enabled, but thats another situation all together.