# PhoneGap APK runs fine but crashes on each run after Google Play deployment

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have built an application for a large multicultural festival in my city that kicks off on Saturday. I've tweaked a lot of bugs in the iPhone version and we are waiting for Apple to approve it. I have taken that perfected version as the basis for the Android version.

The Android version looks and works great. I can run it on my Samsung Galaxy S II by either "Run as Android Application" in Eclipse or by uploading it to a server and downloading it into the phone. I can also email the app to myself and it works, too. I submitted it to the Google Play store and once it got into the wild (this is advertised on billboards, buses, everywhere) it crashes the minute it is opened.

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot this when it works fine on the device before publication. I read about how it has to do with the MainActivity activity name, but everything looks like it lines up.

Error 1 [ClassNotFoundException in PathClassLoader.findClass()]:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.honestapi.folk2011/com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama in loader 
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.honestapi.folk2011-1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.honestapi.folk2011-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
```

Error 2 [ClassNotFoundException in BaseDexClassLoader.findClass()]:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity    
ComponentInfo{com.honestapi.folk2011/com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama}:        
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.honestapi.folk2011.Folklorama
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am in quite the pickle.

Edit - Here is the AndroidManifest.xml from the bin folder

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"   android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="false" android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"       android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"           android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"              android:screenOrientation="landscape"               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"               android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/share_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml please of the version that was submitted to the Google Play store.

Comment: Is this the one from the bin folder or the main project folder?

Comment: This is probably related with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app/10982306#10982306 See there also my response, in my case it appears in relation with the app's icon, either because it was missing in some folder, or was to big, sometimes also clean and rebuild also fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my main Java file was named "MainActivity.java" but it was being called as "Folklorama.java" throughout the project files. I renamed the file to Folklorama.java.