# Android "ClassNotFoundException" occurs sometimes

Tags: android

I recently released my app to the market and my app is crashing when loaded for a few users. I cannot reproduce the error on my phone or on my emulator. Here is the stack..

Any reason the app is crashing for a few people? Has anyone experienced this problem?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
xyz.android.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz.android.MyApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/rageup.android.official-2.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:671)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4322)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:129)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2155)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz.android.MyApplication in loader     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/xyz.android.official-2.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:666)
... 11 more
```

Here is a snippet of my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xyz.android.official"
android:versionCode="AAA"
android:versionName="AAA" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<application
    android:name="xyz.android.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Here is my the MyApplication class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{ 

public int someVar = 555;
private static MyApplication me;

@Override
public void onCreate() {        
    super.onCreate();
    me = this ;
}

public void setSomeVar(int someVar)
{       
    this.someVar = someVar;
}

public int getSomeVar()
{
    return someVar;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
     return me;
}

}
```

Comment: did you change your build target recently?

Comment: I did before I launched the app to the market

Comment: what target build before and now?

Comment: I posted some more of my Manifest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17048/discussion-between-helmib-and-james-fazio)

Answer (score 0):

This mostly caused changed of target build. Some says you need to change library folder to `lib` from `libs`, other says you should write `.MyApplication` in Manifest.xml.

source : [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)

Comment: This looks like it could do the trick, but I don't seem to even have a lib folder.

Comment: your manifest.xml `<application android:name="xyz.android.MyApplication"` change to -> `<application android:name=".MyApplication"` or `<application  android:name=".android.MyApplication"`

Comment: Both of those changes crash the app on the emulator.

Comment: I see some suggestions here, but I do not have a "lib" folder in my project

Comment: This also sometimes happens randomly with exported apps. I haven't found a solution yet, but re-exporting it a couple of times seems to work. I suspect proguard is doing weird stuff.

Comment: It depends on where **MyApplication** is created. If it's in the top level package, then declaring it as `.MyApplication` will suffice. If it's in a sub-package, then it should be declared as `.<subpackage>.MyApplication`, where **<subpackage>** is the actual name of the package.