# Android project does not work in a different development environment

Tags: android, eclipse, development-environment, adt

I have an Android project that works ok on a computer with Eclipse Indigo 64 bits and ADT version 15. In another computer I installed Eclipse Indigo 32 bits and the new ADT and the same project don't works and say that not found main activity class. I unzip the apk and the .dex file and the class exists.

Is something new with new versions of ADT that produces this error? The manifest is wrong for this projects?

Comment: Can you run another Android projects in the 32 bit eclipse? If you try to add your project like you're doing it in the 32 bit eclipse to the 64 bit eclipse (as second project), does it run?

Comment: We have computers with eclipse 32 bits and ADT 15 and it works

Comment: Yes I mean re-add the project to the 32 bits eclipse - to exclude that something with export/import is wrong.

Comment: I did and the project was with maven and I created a new project without maven and put all the dependences manually and when the new project generates a new apk with the same problem (Cannot load AP_NAME/PATH.TO.MAIN.ACTIVITY.MAIN_ACTIVITY.class)

Comment: So the problem is not the eclipse then. Isn't the problem maybe this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app/10982306#10982306 Or post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was that with old versions of ADT in `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` isn't needed mark the libraries that are needed to put inside the APK. In new versions is mandatory mark this libraries.