# Unable to connect with mysql database using android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse

My MainActivity.java class is:

The error is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
>
> error in getData() and in onClick()

I added volley library.While running the app, after button click unfortunately app closed appears.. Database connection failed.

```
private void getData() {
String id = id1.getText().toString().trim();
if (id.equals("")) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return;
}
loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);
String url = Config.DATA_URL+id1.getText().toString().trim();
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
loading.dismiss();
showJSON(response);
}
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String name="";
    String age="";
    String address="";
    String district= "";
    String state="";
    String block="";
    String panchayat="";
    String phone="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject farmerData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        age=farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_AGE);
        address = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        district = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_DISTRICT);
        state = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_STATE);
        panchayat = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_PANCHAYAT);
        block = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_BLOCK);
        phone = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_PHONE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textView1.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAge:\t"+age+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nDistrict:\t"+district+"\nState:\t"+state+"\nPanchayat:\t"+panchayat+"\nBlock:\t"+block+"\nPhone:\t"+phone);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();
}
```

Comment: you might need this reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import the volley [aar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.mcxiaoke.volley%22) file into your project. It will solve the problem.

Comment: This error happen when the module is not properly sync with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the following ?

[Android error - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641739/android-error-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-ut)
[Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)
[android studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724642/android-studio-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

These errors look to be the same : your library is not properly exported