# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for my app

Tags: java, android

I recently just received a bug report from device "Desire HD (ace)" which I cannot recreate for the life of me.  I looked over [Here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything) and [Here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app) but it didn't seem like it would help me with my problem or I am just not understanding this enough to know if this is the fix to my problem.

My LogCat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11-2/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
... 11 more
```

My Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="19"
android:versionName="2.7" >

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- Special case for HTC One -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- Special case for Android DNA -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/b_promo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/i_topbarimage1"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GodStatComparison"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleTimers"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleInfoTablet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JungleTimersTablet"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TopPlayers"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here are images of my "Properties" > "Java Build Path" if this may help solve this problem :

[image]

[image]

("Projects" tab is empty)

[image]

Please let me know if there is any other sort of information you need.

Edit :

```
package joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11;

public class Splash extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

Comment: Post the declaration (including package statement) for the class? This usually indicates that you have a mismatch between your config file and the fully-qualified class name.

Comment: @chrylis I am a bit of a noob here, really sorry. Do you want me to post basically the top of my Splash class?

Comment: The whole Splash class is probably easiest. The most important things I'm looking for are the `package` line and the `public class` line.

Comment: @chrylis added the package line and public class line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible their device is fubar'd, but I also just noticed your project is setup for JDK builds instead of ADT. You'll want to make sure everything is set up using `Properties` -> `Android` instead of `Properties` -> `Java Build`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965393/2640693).

[Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

It appears others are also having similar issues after upgrading to ADT version 22, so there may be a bug in the SDK. I just checked to see what version I have and found an update to Ver. 22.2.1 available.

[Libraries do not get added to APK after update to ADK 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Comment: I guess this is where I am really confused.  So I guess I did it "The Wrong Way" as described in your link "here".  So would I have to undo this? (If I do which Screenshot or tab should I do my removal in?).  

So for me to do this the right way I should be going to Properties -> Android and in "Project Build Target" and Select my Target (which is 17) and in "Library" select the check box "isLibrary"?  Also I cannot add anything when I click the "Add" feature in the Library section, it is all just blank.

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm not really sure why that setup wouldn't work for you. I just checked my projects and even the the android samples are setup like that. Have you tried updating the ADK again and doing a clean build?

Comment: I have not had an error since that user has reported it (or multiple users with the same device).  I did though have in my Properties > Android that the Project Build Target didn't match the one in my Manifest file so I went ahead and fixed that.  So I think it was their device being foobar or my small mistake there.  I will be putting out another update on it in 2 days that I hope to never see that error again or at least once in a blue moon.  Thanks again Jon for the follow up, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed it on my Desire HD fine. Installed itself to SD card by default. So probably what @Jon said.