# Can't compile example gluon project in netbeans

Tags: android, gradle, gluon, javafxports, retrolambda

I tried to release android apk from example gluon project in netbeans but it didn't work.

build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/un5uBh7h
error: http://pastebin.com/aW6ebPPR

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on working app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)

Comment: nope it's not a doplication of this, there is a problem i guess with retrolambda

Comment: Does it happen with the templates from the Gluon plugin for NetBeans, without any modification? Can you run successfully `gradlew android`, or `gradlew androidInstall`?

Comment: Also, about the Android platform, do you have Android 23 (M) or 24 (N) sdk installed? Do you have Android build tools 23 or 24?

Comment: Yes it also happens when i run gradlew android or gradlew androidInstall through cmd. My sdk is 24 (N), android build tools version: 24.0.3

Comment: I've successfully tested this on Mac and Windows. Which is your gradle version? Are you using the wrapper (`gradlew`)?

Comment: Yes i use wrapper gradlew. I tested many gradle versions like 2.14/2.2/2.5 with the same result.

Comment: Notice on NetBeans, Options->Miscellaneous->Gradle, there is a tick: `Prefer Wrapper`. Also have you tested it on command line, outside NetBeans? On the root of the project, run `gradlew --info android` and see if it helps.

Comment: I tested "gradlew --info android" on command linke outside NetBeans, It gave me the same error: http://pastebin.com/CSBLqt1B

Comment: @José Pereda can you look at this ?

Comment: Did you try it always over the same project? Try to clean the cache: delete the `.nb-gradle`, `.gradle` and `private` folders of the project, and run again on command line `gradlew --info clean android`

Comment: Deleting cache didn't help: http://pastebin.com/GWVXiXvS     Nope i tried with many projects, all give the same error.

Comment: @José Pereda Maybe this is the problem ? "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks"

Comment: I finally found another solution for the problem. Thanks for help @José Pereda

Comment: I see a difference in your output, line 142, Classpath: it doesn't contain the android.jar, and it should. Probably this leads to the error. I thought it was related to retrolambda, but maybe you are not adding the right path for the android sdk. On NetBeans, do you see the android.jar under Dependencies->Compile for Android?

Comment: I just added "compile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'android-all', version: '5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1'" into dependecies :)

Comment: I don't see why you need that, but probably it solves your issue. Anyway, make sure you add the right path of the android sdk (case sensitive) and you have android.jar under dependencies for android.

Comment: @José Pered Could you tell me why ported javafx apps into android have poor performance? And how to solve it ?

Comment: Create a new question for this, and specify what are you testing and which is your device

Comment: Ok i just created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369300/poor-performance-of-javafx-ported-app