# Application class not found after upgrading to Android X

Tags: android, androidx

I am facing one very weird issue.
I have migrated one of my old projects to `AndroidX`.
And I have upgraded all the dependencies so I would get all the dependencies with `AndroidX` support also.

But somehow after doing all this, My app is crashing with this error log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.MYApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MYApplication"

Did anyone face the same issue?
Please let me know any solutions.

Comment: I haven't had this, but start by sharing your manifest and gradle dependencies, maybe they will have clues

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild? Upload your Manifest.xml. We need more informations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on working app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)

Comment: invalidate caches and restart usually fixes any android x migration issues for me

Comment: I have tried doing clean and rebuild, invalid cache and restart, but not working after also

Comment: I'm having this problem too, did you ever find a solution?